# jQuery: How to map element which are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some TR in table which has class `parent_0`. I am using `map()` of jQuery to get all elements in map which are not `hidden`.

**DOM:**

```
<table id="tableID" class="tableClass">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th width="3px">Header1</th>
        <th align="left">Header2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left">
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td><a <i id="1" class="parent_0" ></i>></a>Data12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left" style="display: none;">
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td><a <i id="2" class="parent_0"></i>></a>Data22</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$( document ).ready(function(){ 
    allChildern = $(".parent_0").map(function() {
        return this.id
    }).get();
    alert(allChildern)

    var allSubChildern = $(".parent_0").map(function() {
       if($('#'+this.id).closest('tr').is(':visible')){
           return this.id //its working but taking so much time for 1k records.
       }
    }).get();
    alert(allSubChildern)
});
```

Is there any function to map elements which are only visible.

Here is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sohampshetty/d2ob1cpk/). Thank you.

Comment: `visible` with class `parent_0`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hd0dsx8g/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get all `visible` rows then continue using `.map()`

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
var allSubChildern = $(".parent_0").filter(function(){
    return $(this).closest('tr').is(':visible');
}).map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
alert(allSubChildern)
```

Or, Alternatively you can also use

```
var allSubChildern = $("#tableID tr:visible .parent_0").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really worried about performance and can alter the html then a better solution would be is to use a class to hide the element.

ie, define a class like `.hidden{display: none}` then use that in the tr to hide the elements(`<tr align="left" class="hidden">` instead of `<tr align="left" style="display: none;">`), so you can use pure css selectors to select the elements which will increase the speed like

```
  var allSubChildern = $("#tableID tr:not(.hidden) .parent_0").map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).get();
```

The model which uses `:visible` [takes around](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hd0dsx8g/7/) 55-70ms, where as [the above](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hd0dsx8g/6/) takes only 1-3ms in the fiddle

Comment: Thank you. But the class will get dynamically when I hide records using function `hide()`. Anyways it worked with Satpal Solution.